# A question on finitely generated modules over Z in matrix form

Tags: matrices, group-theory, integer-lattices, finitely-generated

in my class on module theory I have been given this problem on finitely generated $ \mathbb{Z} $ modules (Abelian groups) stating the following:

> We define the vectors $ v_1 = (1,0,-1) $ $ v_2 = (2,-3,1) $ $ v_3 = (0,2,1) $ 
>   $ v_3 = (3,1,5) $. We are to show that these vectors span the whole of $ \mathbb{Z}^3 $ and also that any subset of them consisting of three vectors does not span $ \mathbb{Z}^3 $

Now I know that there is the brute force solution with systems of linear equations and taking all 4 possible subsets consisting of three elements but I figured it has something to do with matrix form, but unfortunately I cannot do this, so I am kindly asking for help in a solution to this with some explanation, I thank all helpers

Comment: Gave second answer, the mistake was mine, i copied a number from you vectors incorrectly. You are right to think in terms of matrices.

Comment: For all four vectors, the sum of the three entries is divisible by $3.$ This will also be true for any integer linear combination of all four. So, there really is a difficulty with the problem.  I noticed this by doing Gauss elimination on the rectangular three by four, then including a fifth augmenting column, and i kept needing to throw in factors of $3$ to avoid using fractions. $1+0-1=0,$ $2-3+1=0,$ $0+2+1 = 3,$ $3+1+5 = 9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected, I hope.

$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -3 & 2 \\
-1 &   -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

All we really need to know is that the determinant is not $\pm 1,$ it is actually $-5.$

$$
R^{-1} =
\frac{1}{5}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & -4 \\
2 & -1 & 2 \\
3 &   1 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Is it possible to represent $(1,0,0)$ as $x v_1 + y v_2 + z v_3?$ No, because we see from $R^{-1}$ that $x = 1/5, y = 2/5, z= 3/5.$ That is, $(1,0,0)$ is not in the span of the first three given vectors.

Do the same for the other three triples. Then, for the four triples, you get a rectangular matrix, use Gaussian elimination to show that there is an integer quadruple to represent any target vector $(a,b,c).$ ADDENDUM: no, only represent $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$ Some error, not mine this time.

Answer (score 2):

I miscopied, I put a $3$ where it should be $-3.$ I will leave this here.

There is an error. Take the matrix $R$ with the first three vectors as columns. This has determinant $1.$ If we have a column vector $A$ of three integers and want to represent it as $RX$ with $X$ an unknown column of integers, we just need $X = R^{-1}A.$

If $X$ is the column vector with entries $x,y,z,$ then the vector (as a column) corresponding to $x v_1 + y v_2 + z v_3$ is the $RX$ I mentioned. You should check that by hand.
$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 2 \\
-1 &   -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
R^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & -2 & 4 \\
-2 & 1 & -2 \\
3 &   -1 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This topic is in "integer lattices," which are positive definite quadratic forms with all integer coefficients.

Comment: Thanks but I do not understand what the error is? I am treating the spaces as row vector modules

Comment: I added a small paragraph. The first three do span $\mathbb Z^3.$

Comment: OK so the question has a mistake then

Comment: @AbeerAbassi Actually, I looked again, I copied a $3$ where there is actually a $-3,$ and the determinant switches to $-5.$ I will post a separate answer I think.